# Returning area of interest image upon lat/long input?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-online-basemaps

I would like to know if it's possible to give a latitude and longitude (or bounding box) for a certain location and return an area of interest image, including a target property and a list of nearby schools. Me and my manager went through the Esri docs but couldn't find a way of doing it. If not, any suggestion for a different api to do that?

I would like to get something like this image below where the red point of interest is a property and the black ones are nearby schools:

[image]

I am using the esri rest api.

Comment: Cross-posted as https://stackoverflow.com/q/54301860/820534

Comment: The undesirability of cross-posting is described at https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64073/215590